# Merging HList elements

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have a simple service definition

```
trait Service[-Req, +Rep] extends (Req => Future[Rep]) {
    def apply(request: Req): Future[Rep]
}
```

and a method how to chain services:

```
implicit class ServiceOps1[Req, RepIn](service: Service[Req, RepIn]) {
    def -->[RepOut](next: Service[RepIn, RepOut]): Service[Req, RepOut] =
        (req: Req) => service(req) flatMap next
}
```

I would like to put all my service (in assumption that they could be composed) into `HList` and then build from `HList` a composition of service.

Here is my `Resolver`

```
  trait Resolver[L <: HList, In] {
    type Out
    def apply(l: L): Service[In, Out]
  }

  object Resolver {
    def apply[L <: HList, In](implicit resolver: Resolver[L, In]): Aux[L, In, resolver.Out] = resolver

    type Aux[L <: HList, In, Out0] = Resolver[L, In] { type Out = Out0 }

    implicit def hsingleResolver[I, O, S <: Service[I, O]]: Aux[S :: HNil, I, O] =
      new Resolver[S :: HNil, I] {
        type Out = O
        def apply(l : S :: HNil): Service[I, Out] = l.head
      }

    implicit def hlistResolver[I, O, S <: Service[I, O], T <: HList](implicit res : Resolver[T, O]): Aux[S :: T, I, res.Out] =
      new Resolver[S :: T, I] {
        type Out = res.Out

        def apply(l: S :: T): Service[I, res.Out] = l.head --> res(l.tail)
      }
  }
```

I have a service

```
object S extends Service[Int, String] {
    def apply(request: Int): Future[String] =  Future successful request.toString
}
```

When I try to resolve the simple chain

```
implicitly[Resolver[S.type :: HNil, Int]].apply(S :: HNil)
```

I got an implicit not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the type signature of your implicits: `implicit def hsingleResolver[I, O, S <: Service[I, O]]: Aux[S :: HNil, I, O]`. Here because of `S <: Service[I, O]` you expect `O` to be inferred based on the type of `S`, but unfortunately that's not how it works. The `S <: Service[I, O]` clause in the type parameter list is not taken into consideration for inferring the type arguments. What happens when you invoke `implicitly[Resolver[S.type :: HNil, Int]]` is that the compiler sees that `S = S.type`, `I = Int` and `O` is unknown so `O = Nothing`. Then afterwards it goes on to check that `S <: Service[Int,Nothing]` which is false and implicit search fails.

So to fix this you have to make the fact that `S <: Service[I, O]` part of the implicit search/type inference process. For instance in one of these ways:

```
implicit def hsingleResolver[I, O, S](implicit ev: S <:< Service[I,O]): Aux[S :: HNil, I, O] // option 1
implicit def hsingleResolver[I, O, S]: Aux[(S with Service[I,O]) :: HNil, I, O] // option 2
```

As a side note: wouldn't it make more sense to define `Resolver` in the following way?

```
trait Resolver[L <: HList] {
  type In
  type Out
  def apply(l: L): Service[In, Out]
}

object Resolver {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit resolver: Resolver[L]): Aux[L, resolver.In, resolver.Out] = resolver

  type Aux[L <: HList, In0, Out0] = Resolver[L] { type In = In0; type Out = Out0 }

  ...
}
```

Because `In` is also dependent on `L`, just like `Out`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this was down voted, maybe you could have made a sample repo available. Anyway, here's a partial answer, maybe this get's you back on track.

1) enable debug options for implicits in your build.sbt: `scalacOptions += "-Xlog-implicits"`

2) define a resolver for HNil: `implicit def hNilResolver[I]: Aux[HNil, I, HNil] = ???`

3) following the debug output, fix the remainder :)